# Invisible Marker in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I've got an unusual error and I might be missing something - I've written a test plugin that should simply show an error marker on the first line of a file. I'm using this code, triggered from a button press

```
public void createMarkerForResource(IResource resource) throws CoreException {
        HashMap map = new HashMap();
        MarkerUtilities.setLineNumber(map, 1);
        MarkerUtilities.setMessage(map, "HAZARD");
        map.put(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_WARNING);
        MarkerUtilities.createMarker(resource, map, IMarker.TEXT);
    }
```

The code appeared not to work - but on closer inspection *something* is happening. There is now a 'clickable' area on the ruler, but no icon...

Before: 
[image]

After:
[image]

Any ideas?

(I'm aware there's a similar question - but it was self-solved and  as we are using different approaches and getting different responses I thought it was worth opening this one up.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you define a `org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker`.
But I cannot find a `org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerImageProviders` with an image for the marker type. So I simply believe, there are no image for this type.

Try using a different type of marker type, define your own marker type or define your own image for the `textmarker` marker type (not recommended).

Comment: Perfect - I changed IMarker.TEXT to IMarker.PROBLEM and a nice little icon popped up :)